# Spotifre Message dialog Box action

Tags: spotfire

I have a report where, once the user clicks a SAVE button it fires a script. Can I do a dialog box where once the user clicks SAVE, A dialog with "Confirm save ... Yes? No? " pops up and when the user clicks Yes it fires the script? I would like this to work on both the web player and desktop

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following iron python script for solving this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import MessageBox, MessageBoxButtons
from System.Windows.Forms import DialogResult

dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Some question", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes):
    MessageBox.Show("The answer is YES")
else:
    MessageBox.Show("The answer is NO")
```

Comment: assuming that you are allowed to use iron python for solving the problem

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work in the web player as requested.

Comment: This script not works for web player, can anybody tell how to show a message box in web player?

Comment: @Aashi You have to develop a C# Extention. That can target both the WebPlayer and Analyst. You can read here for getting started with that: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/getting-started-c-extensions-tibco-spotfirer